# How to attach a replicant storage to a VM

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am hitting the following error when I try to attach storage to a VM

SoftLayer_Network_Storage::allowAccessToReplicantFromVirtualGuestList is not implemented.`SoftLayer_Exception_NotImplemented`

I am trying to call the following api
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage//allowAccessToReplicantFromVirtualGuest/

Comment: This is not really a coding problem but rather a server related question. Also it seems that their api is not fully released and that this feature is not implemented yet.

Comment: I get the exact same error when I try it with another API call that I know for sure is implemented and works allowAccessFromVirtualGuest , so I assumed that replicant disks cannot be authorized using the that API call and tried the replicant specific one , but still hit the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For me the method is working fine this is the RESTFUL I used:

```
GET https://$USERID:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$StorageID/allowAccessToReplicantFromVirtualGuest

Payload:
{
    "parameters": [{"id": 11111}]
}

Note: 11111 is the id of the virtual guest
```

Now there is something to point out the method only should work for Block and File storages devices if you are trying to use it with other devices you will get error, because those devices may not support to allow access from a virtual guest. So make sure that you are using the method for valid devices.

Regards

Comment: can you tell me how I would make this call from a browser ```https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/<volumeid>/allowAccessToReplicantFromVirtualGuest/<vm>``` this is what I did , maybe my call is wrong ??.This is a endurance block storage device

Comment: You need a REST client like Postman using browser I do not believe that is possbile you need to send the data using the POST method the browsers only work with GET method